# Debian Sources List

Tags: apt

Working with Debian here. I'm having trouble with apt-get. I did go into the sources list and comment out anything referring to a CD drive. It no longer points to a CD drive; however, whenever I run apt-get on anything it tells me that the file is not available but referring to another package... something about being obsolete or missing. The problem is it does it for everything. Any idea what I might be missing?

I am running under root, and a package example is `sudo apt-get install apache2`.

Comment: "The file".   What files it that?  Can you give us the exact error message?

Comment: When asking for help, always include the actual error messages rather than your summary or interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have made any changes to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you will need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

In order for the indexes to be updated. The `sources.list` is just a list of URLs where Debian will look for packages. That is read with the command `apt-get update`
 so until that command is run, you are still using your old ones.